# Combinatorics and geometry basic

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

Let $A$ be a set of $n$ points in the plane such that, for each point $P \in A$, $P$ is equidistant to at least $k$ other points in $A$. Show that $k < \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{2n}.$

Can anyone help me in this matter? I'm not able to interpret this. Thanks.

Comment: n=4, k<3.328427125 - I do not see how 4 points may be placed on a plane in a way that each one of them is equidistant from all other 3.

Comment: @Moti: 2 is less than 3.

Comment: Actually I misread the challenge - each point of the 4 could be at equal distance from the others. You are right - 2 < 3:)